# Use Google analytics in NetSuite

Tags: html, wordpress, analytics, netsuite

I have a wordpress site and my client wants to integrate Netsuite analytics to this external site. Is it possible to add Netsuite analytics to it? If yes can anyone tell me the steps to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found out that Netsuite allows Google analytics integration.

To do that follow the below steps:-

To integrate your NetSuite web site with Google Analytics:

**1.** **Prerequisite steps:**

**a.**  Create your own account with Google Analytics. For more information, visit the Google Analytics Web site.
**b.**  In Google Analytics, add a profile for the domain you want to track.
**c.**  On the Standard tab, select multiple top-level domains.
**d.**  Copy the tracking pixel code provided for you by Google Analytics.
**e.**  Click Save and Finish.
**f.**  In the Website Profiles list, click Edit next to the profile you want to enable.
**g.**  On the Profile Settings page, click Edit next to Main Website Profile Information.
**h.**  Set the E-Commerce Website radio button to Yes.
**i.**  Click Save Changes.

**2.**  Log in to NetSuite.

**3.**  Go to Setup > Site Builder > Set Up Web Site. 
Click the Analytics subtab to enter your tracking snippet, along with HTML code and web site tags for tracking analytics data.

**Important: 
If you have a hosted site, paste your Google Analytics tracking snippet in your hosted HTML pages. Then, enter custom analytics tracking code in the Analytics Click Attributes, Analytics Submit Attributes, and Order Tracking Script HTML fields. When you do this, web site tags you use to create links to forms and checkout pages will collect tracking data across domains.**

[image]

**a.**  **Addition to <head>** – Paste your Google Analytics tracking snippet in this field. Your tracking code is then added to every page of your NetSuite-generated site.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-9UA-20948874-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

**b.** **Analytics Click Attributes** – Add attributes for the Add To Cart button. The code in this field modifies link URLs by adding your tracking pixel. This applies to links for registration, checkout, and any other links that go to checkout pages. Use this syntax:

```
onclick="if(typeof(_gaq._getAsyncTracker) == 'undefined') { return true; } else { _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]); return false; }"
```

**c. Analytics Submit Attributes** – Add attributes for the Proceed to Checkout button. Code in this field captures analytics data when shoppers go to checkout from the shopping cart, and when they submit forms on your web site. Use this syntax:

```
onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]); return true;"
```

**d.    Order Tracking Script HTML** – Code in this field, is applied to the order confirmation page, or Thank You page, that displays after a shopper submits a Web order on your site. You can use the sample code provided below to get started. Replace the account number in the sample, with your own Google Analytics account number:

```
    

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-9']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

        _gaq.push(['_addTrans',     
        "",           
        "",  
        "",          
        "",           
        "",     
        "",    
        "",      
        ""]);    

        var itemsInOrder = "";

        var lineItem = itemsInOrder.split("||");

        for(var inum = 0; inum ",     
                itemAttributes[0],           
                itemAttributes[1],           
                itemAttributes[2],        
                itemAttributes[3],   
                itemAttributes[4]]);
        }

        _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); 

        (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
```

**4.**  Check the Enable Google Analytics Integration box.
Check this box to pass Google tracking cookies from shopping to checkout. This along with the fields on the Analytics subtab are required for cross-domain analytics tracking to integrate NetSuite with your Google Analytics account. Clear this box if Google Analytics Integration interferes with a custom solution you have already implemented for cross-domain tracking.

**5.**  Click Save.

After adding your tracking code to the site, you can verify data is being captured on the order confirmation page. Place a test order, and then on the Thank You page, select View Source from the View menu in the browser. You should see values for each tag included in the script you added to the Order Script Tracking HTML field.

Hope this helps someone...